# SELECT with 9 columns in a WHERE or GROUP BY. Is there a better way to index multiple columns than a composite index for almost each permutation?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, multi-index

I have 9 columns in a table with 500 million rows in which I will do SELECT queries and all of the columns may or may not be in a WHERE or GROUP BY.

For example:
Columns -> `(A, B, C, D, E, F, I, J, K)`
query ->

```
SELECT * 
FROM table WHERE A = 'x' AND J = 'y' GROUP BY B, E, K
```

What is the best way to indexing and optimize the database? Do I have to do a multiple column index (composite index) for each permutation of columns?

For 3 columns I know I could do: 
(a, b, c), (b, c), (c), (a, c)
but what about 9 columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve the desired goal.  Some possible alternatives:

- Discover which columns are most commonly used; then make up to 10 indexes with up to 3 columns each.  If you help the most common combinations, then it might be "good enough".
- Look into MariaDB with "Columnstore".
- Look into addon packages.

Answer (score 0):

First, `select *` is not appropriate with `group by`.  Happily, MySQL no longer allows that syntax (by default).

If you intend:

```
SELECT B, E, K
FROM table
WHERE A = 'x' AND J = 'y'
GROUP BY B, E, K;
```

Then the best index is on `(A, J, B, E, K)`;

Comment: This query was an example. All of the columns may or may not be in the WHERE or GROUP BY clause.

It Could be:
"SELECT B, E, K FROM table WHERE A = 'x' AND J = 'y' GROUP BY B, E, K;" OR
"SELECT F, G FROM table WHERE B = 'x' AND D = 'y' GROUP BY F, G"
...

Comment: I have to create a composite index for almost each permutation of columns?

Comment: @shadow . . . You should focus on the equality conditions in the `where` clause.  Those should be the leading columns in an index.

Comment: But all of the 9 columns could be in the WHERE clause. I have to create a composite index for each permutation of columns?